# Angular Universal - Several instances of the script injected by TransferState (<script id="myapp-state">...</script>)

Tags: angular, angular-universal, angular-transfer-state

I have an Angular 7 application with Angular Universal implemented. It's a pretty big application with several lazy loaded modules. I use the `TransferState` module, and everything goes well, eeeeexcept that in *some* pages, the script injected by the `TransferState` module is "double". There are at least two instances, like:

```
<script id="myapp-state">{ objectA }</script>
<script id="myapp-state">{ objectB }</script>
```

And what's worse, the content inside both is *different*. Therefore, when the client app loads, sometimes it tries to retrieve data that is stored in *objectB* but cannot find it in *objectA*, which is the one checked because... it's the first one? (That's internal logic of the `TransferState` module, I assume).

I don't have too many hopes on an answer, since I can't really provide too much documentation, but maybe someone has experienced a similar issue.

What could be the reason? What part of the `TransferState` module is in charge of injecting this script and why doesn't it throw an error when there's already one?

Update:

Here's the `main.browser.ts` file:

```
if (environment.production) {
    enableProdMode();
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    platformBrowserDynamic()
        .bootstrapModule(BrowserAppModule)
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
});
```

and here's the `main.server.ts` file:

```
if (environment.production) {
    enableProdMode();
}

export { ServerAppModule } from './app/server.app.module';
```

My `server.app.module.ts`:

```
@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        AppModule,
        ServerModule,
        BrowserModule.withServerTransition({
            appId: APPLICATION_NAME
        }),
        NoopAnimationsModule,
        ModuleMapLoaderModule,
        ServerTransferStateModule
    ]
})
export class ServerAppModule {
}
```

and my `browser.app.module`:

```
@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule.withServerTransition({
            appId: APPLICATION_NAME
        }),
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        BrowserTransferStateModule,
        AppModule
    ]
})
export class BrowserAppModule {
}
```

And the engine part of my `server.ts`:

```
app.engine('html', (filePath, options, callback) => {
        const engine = ngExpressEngine({
            bootstrap: ServerAppModuleNgFactory,
            providers: [
                provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP),
                { provide: REQUEST, useFactory: () => (options as any).req, deps: [] },
                { provide: RESPONSE, useFactory: () => (options as any).req.res, deps: [] },
                { provide: LOCALES, useFactory: () => allLocalizationStrings, deps: [] },
            ]
        });

        engine(filePath, options as any, callback);
    });
```

UPDATE: It seems to be related with my pre rendering. If I deactivate it, everything works correctly. If I activate it, it does not work correctly regardless of the route I'm rendering. This is how I'm pre rendering at the moment:

```
const html = await renderModuleFactory(ServerAppModuleNgFactory, {
                document: baseIndex,
                url: route,
                extraProviders: [
                    provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP),
                    { provide: IS_PRE_RENDER, useFactory: () => true, deps: [] },
                    { provide: ERROR_WRAPPER, useValue: (errorWrapper) }
                ]
            });
```

Comment: Can you show your `server.ts` and `main.ts` files?

Comment: Sure. I added some of it already. The server.ts is a bit too long, but I can add more if you are interested in something in particular.

Comment: Any update on this? I am having 2 TransferState script Tags and the first one is always empty which makes the whole transferState useless